# Access Properties from a class into another class in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, forms, inheritance, xamarin

I would like to access the email of this class into another class that I am already instantiated on my render page.
Any help very much appreciated.

```
public class Access
    {
        public string Email { get; set; } //I want this value...

    }  
public class Types
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Sum { get; set; }
        public string Addition { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; } // ...to be this value inside my class TYPES
  }
```

Comment: You need to have an instance of Access inside of a Types Instance, or simple set TypesInstance.Email = AccessInstance.Email

Comment: You need to learn to understand [the difference between a class and an instance of the class](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-class-object-and-class-instance). If you have a class named `Access`, there may be a hundred different instances of that class. Each one will have a different `Email` value. Which one of those do you want?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer . I want the value from the class Access , <Email > inside my class Types. how do I access that value from Types.

Comment: public class Types : Access 
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Sum { get; set; }
        public string Addition { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; } // ...to be this value inside my class TYPES
  }

Comment: Perhaps it's better for you to provide additional code for what you're trying to do. The answers above told you what you need to do already, but still, to clarify, provide more info, please.

Comment: @pamela We already read the question, thanks. No need to repeat it. Now it's your turn to read what we told you.

Comment: I am trying to pass the Email value inside this binding context . my page looks like :public partial class TypesView : ContentPage
    {
        
        public TypesView( Types Item  )
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
            this.BindingContext = new { Item, Item.Email };
  
        }

Comment: To display the email in here XAML : <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions ="Center">
                    <Label Text="your email is :" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Item.Email}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </StackLayout>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think you can simply use a copy constructor for the Types class with the Access instance as parameter from which you want to copy the email value when creating a new Types instance.

From what you said it seems you don't care if its a particular instance (as your post is a bit confusing between class and instance)

```
 public class Types
 {
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Sum { get; set; }
  public string Addition { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }

  public Types(Access access)
    {
      Email = access.Email
    }
 }
```